# Is wchar_t guaranteed to be distinct from any integer type?

Tags: c++, c++11, wchar-t

On my system, wchar_t and int are distinct types with the same properties:

```
#include <type_traits>
sizeof(wchar_t) == sizeof(int) == 4
std::is_signed<wchar_t> == std::is_signed<int> == std::true_type
std::is_same<wchar_t, int> == std::false_type
```

In contrast, `ptrdiff_t` and `long int` are identical types (same properties, and `is_same` is true).

Is this distinctness of `wchar_t` guaranteed? Is it safe to overload for `wchar_t` and `int` on all systems? Is there any property in  or elsewhere that distinguishes `wchar_t` and the corresponding int property besides `is_same`?

(System info: I'm interested in the general case, but my tests so far have been on an OS X machine running g++ 4.8.0 and Apple clang++ 4.1, both with -std=c++11.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `wchar_t` is guaranteed to be a distinct type (§3.9.1/5):

> Type `wchar_t` is a distinct type whose values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales (22.3.1).

So yes, it's safe to overload for `wchar_t` and `int` on all systems.

However, `wchar_t` is also guaranteed to have the same size, signedness and alignment requirements as another integral type, which is its *underlying type*. This isn't necessarily `int` but in your case appears to be. This means `wchar_t` is probably implemented using one of the integral types, but as far as you are concerned, they are treated as completely distinct types.

Comment: Short, sweet, and to the point. I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, for C++11, wchar_t is its own type, distinct from any other, but as you've observed, it will also have the same range, signedness, etc., as some other type (§3.9.1/3):

> Type wchar_t is a distinct type whose values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales (22.3.1). Type wchar_t shall have the same size, signedness, and alignment requirements (3.11) as one of the other integral types, called its underlying
>   type.